# Facebook not fetching my website links (SSL related?)

Tags: facebook, ssl, ssl-certificate, facebook-share

I think that installing a SSL cert in my website caused some problems with facebook retrieving my webpage information to be fetched in my links.

Before then, I I think all was working well but now I get errors in facebbok url debuger and not sure how to fix.

Any suggestions?

Site: https://truecounsellor.com.au

many thanks

Comment: btw, I have this problem with all webpages within the website

Comment: Chrome does not complain about the certificate, but f.e. https://www.geocerts.com/ssl_checker says, “The hostname (truecounsellor.com.au) does NOT match the Common Name in the certificate (*.hosting-service.net.au). This certificate is currently invalid for this host.”, and https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker reports that the Root 1 certificate is missing in the chain. Ask your server admin to look into those issues.

Comment: Firefox does complain about your certificate so as CBroe said, I would check with your hosting provider.